# How to restart Sidekiq when running on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, sidekiq, dyno

I am running sidekiq in a worker on Heroku as follows:

`bundle exec sidekiq -t 25 -e $RAILS_ENV -c 3`

One of the operations uses more memory (>500mb) than the worker allows. After the job has completed, the memory still hasn't been released and I get these errors in the heroku rails log files:

`2018-11-13T00:56:05.642142+00:00 heroku[sidekiq_worker.1]: Process running mem=646M(126.4%)
2018-11-13T00:56:05.642650+00:00 heroku[sidekiq_worker.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)`

Is there a way to automatically restart Sidekiq when the memory usage exceeds a certain amount?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to [reduce memory fragmentations](https://www.mikeperham.com/2018/04/25/taming-rails-memory-bloat/)? here [how you can do it in Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/tuning-glibc-memory-behavior).

if that wasn't good enough you can use [Heroku platform gem](https://github.com/heroku/platform-api) and [periodically restart the sidekiq](https://dev.to/nicolrx/how-to-easily-avoid-hitting-the-memory-limit-on-heroku-2mha)